# C# equivalent of Java Memory mapping methods

Tags: java, c#, memory, memory-mapped-files

While translating a Java project to C#, i got stuck with the following piece:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, length);
```

I'm not familiar with the memory mapping conception, I found a `MemoryMappedFile` class in C#, but don't know how to use it properly like in the Java code above (the `MappedByteBuffer` is used to obtain a large binary file, about 600-700MB).

Can anyone tell me how to translate the piece above properly?

Comment: MSDN to the recue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997372%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fileName, FileMode.Read);
using (MemoryMappedViewStream vs = mmf.CreateViewStream()) {
    // perform stream operations
}
```

A [MemoryMappedViewStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewstream(v=vs.110).aspx) is a thin veneer onto the memory.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I write a buffer to a file then (with `FileMode.Create`, of course)? For example I have a function `packPrunTable(table, buffer, FILE_SIZE)`, and I want the `buffer` to be mapped to file?